# install package using pip (version confused)

Tags: path, pip, package

I think since I'm new to python, I installed packages in multiple subversion. like python 2.7.15 or python 2.7.14.

If I import certain package (e.g., hdf5storage) using terminal (python 2.7.15), I can >> import hdf5storage

but if I import the package using jupyter notebook (python 2.7.14), i cannot. >> import hdf5storage
no module called hdf5storage. 
I didn't install this different version on purpose, it just happened.

I used pip2 to install packages. Can anyone explain how to solve this issue, for a beginner? How do I use virtualenv or edit PATH, it's very confusing for me. Any answer would be appreciated!